# How to update 2 select boxes with same option using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

Using jquery/jqm I need to add an option to 2 selectboxes.  I can get one to update but not the other.  How do I get the other one to update.
Notice the S in the names/id's
Whichever .append is listed 2nd is the one that is updated.

html:

```
<input type="button" name="Goal_WeightVar" id="Goal_WeightVar" value="doit">
<br>
<select name="grouplist" id="grouplist">
  <option value="choose">Choose a Group</option>
  <option value="#groupid#">option1</option>
</select>
<select name="groupslist" id="groupslist">
  <option value="choose">Choose a Group</option>
  <option value="#groupid#">option1</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
$('#Goal_WeightVar').live('click', function() {
  var newgroupcode = $('<option value="11">11<option>');
  $('#groupslist').append(newgroupcode).trigger("create");
  $('#grouplist').append(newgroupcode).trigger("create");
  $('#groupslist').selectmenu();
  $('#groupslist').selectmenu('refresh');
  $('#grouplist').selectmenu();
  $('#grouplist').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/ThMnq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**clone()**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to make a copy of your object and to add different objects as one object could not exists in two places.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ThMnq/3/)**

```
$('#Goal_WeightVar').live('click', function() {
  var newgroupcode = $('<option value="11">11<option>');
  $('#groupslist').append(newgroupcode).trigger("create");
  $('#grouplist').append(newgroupcode.clone()).trigger("create");    
});
```